# How to change encoding of the mysql dump files

Tags: mysql, encoding

How to change encoding of the mysql dump files?
When I run mysqldump command it creates file encoded in ANSI. How to change it to utf-8? I have also tried to do this:

```
mysqldump --user=user1--password=pas1 --default-character-set=utf8 mydb1 mytbl1 > e:\1.sql
```

Comment: "Encoded in ANSI" - I doubt that. Where do you have this information from? Note that text editors are not always successful in detecting encodings. 

My bet is that the encoding already *is*  UTF-8.

Comment: I opened dump file in the notepad++. Also I see '?'-symbols instead of russian symbols.

Comment: does Notepad++ have an encoding menu? Try selecting UTF-8 there. I'm willing to bet a beer that it'll work then

Comment: Yes, it has. I tried to convert and watch it like UTF-8, but it does not help.

Comment: don't try to convert it, just switch the *view* to UTF-8 without any conversion.

Comment: I did it, but I see only '?' instead of russian symbols.

Comment: maybe Notepad++'s font can't show cyrillic symbols. I'm still fairly sure the dump file is fine. Try re-importing it into the database or opening it in a browser which should have better font support

Comment: When I read data from mysql db with c# and then save it to file I see file encoding like utf-8 and I also see russian symbols. But I need to do it with mysqldump.

Comment: ah, it seems you're right. I apologize. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this forum thread, the culprit is the `> filename` redirection on Windows, which seems to have trouble with UTF-8 characters.

Try using the [`--result-file` parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file) instead.

Comment: Wow, this really saved my day!

Comment: There is no forum thread linked. Also, I'm pretty sure Windows (well, `cmd.exe` to be precise) performs binary redirection, so if this fix helps, it's only because mysqldump does something silly when outputting to stdout on Windows.